# mini linux to use dd and access HD and/or USB

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, linux-distributions

I was thinking about something.
I want to install a 7gb partition and store 2 compress disk image and install linux to it. I want it to be light. What i would like to do is hide the grub loader (or anything) and if i want to reformat my PC press a certain key on startup. Which will then load the linux OS and then i can use dd to restore the partition i want

I plan to use windows XP and windows 7 as my main OS and virtualize anything else i need (vista, dummy XP for testing, multiple linux distos, etc).

Bonus points if you can tell me how to hide the partition in windows so XP and 7 cant touch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to install a small distro such as [Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.com/) or Damn Small Linux. Once you've done this use Super Grub Disk to restore the Windows bootloader to the MBR and when you need to access the Linux partition, use Super Grub Disk again.